# Synchronize access to keys stored in distributed cache (SharedCache)

Tags: .net, thread-safety, web-farm, distributed-caching, shared-cache

In my project I am using [SharedCache](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/) as a distributed caching mechanism. There are multiple instances of a service deployed in webfarm which accesses this cached data. The data which is cached is transient and can have updates. I would like to know if there is any way we can synchronize the access to the data between two or more services?

To give you an example here is a scenario, imagine there are 2 instances of a service running. Both the instances are accessing the shared cache. If one service picks up some data from the cache for processing I would want the other service to not pick the same information. For that I need to update the cache with some status saying unavailable. But while I am updating the status, it might happen that the second service might also pick the same data.

Shared cache doccumentation [thread safety](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/default.aspx?pg=a1c72858-9090-4b33-9d0f-92b43e895270) suggests that the data is globaly available and is not thread safe. Is there a way to make it thread safe without changing the source code of SharedCache?

Comment: I went through the code of SharedCache. It is having a lock around methods like Add and Remove.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by myself there is a lock within sharedcache code and its syncronized. hence voting for closing of this question.